# How do I safely edit a system file using a debian package?

Tags: debian, packages

I'm creating a debian package and I'm wondering if there's a safe way to modify system files. For example, when `postinst` executes I want to edit `/etc/login.defs` to alter a setting. I could use sed to do this, which would leave the rest of the file intact.

I'd like to make this something completely reversible, but I'm not sure what Debian packages typically do in this situation. Do they just create a backup named something like `/etc/file.conf.backup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages should never modify files belonging to other packages.

See http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html at 10.7.4

You can't just edit a configuration file belonging to another package. If that package supports conf.d directory you can put your own configuration file into it.

If the package from where the conffile comes does not provide any tool to edit it, you should ask the question to the debian-devel mailing list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Better if i explain WHY he can't to that?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the brevity

Answer (score 0):

I think `dpkg-divert` might be a good solution to my problem: http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html